# Static Member Indexed Properties

Tags: f#

Is it possible to create static member indexed properties in F#? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233202.aspx) show them only for instance members, however, I'm able to define the following class:

```
type ObjWithStaticProperty =
    static member StaticProperty
        with get () = 3
        and  set (value:int) = ()

    static member StaticPropertyIndexed1
        with get (x:int) = 3
        and  set (x:int) (value:int) = ()

    static member StaticPropertyIndexed2
        with get (x:int,y:int) = 3
        and  set (x:int,y:int) (value:int) = ()

//Type signature given by FSI:
type ObjWithStaticProperty =
  class
    static member StaticProperty : int
    static member StaticPropertyIndexed1 : x:int -> int with get
    static member StaticPropertyIndexed2 : x:int * y:int -> int with get
    static member StaticProperty : int with set
    static member StaticPropertyIndexed1 : x:int -> int with set
    static member StaticPropertyIndexed2 : x:int * y:int -> int with set
  end
```

But when I try to use one, I get an error:

```
> ObjWithStaticProperty.StaticPropertyIndexed2.[1,2] <- 3;;

  ObjWithStaticProperty.StaticPropertyIndexed2.[1,2] <- 3;;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error FS1187: An indexer property must be given at least one argument
```

I tried a few different syntax variations and none worked.  Also weird is that when I hover over `set` in VS2010 for one of the definitions in the type, I get info about `ExtraTopLevelOperators.set`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you call indexed properties using a different syntax (whether instance or static):

```
ObjWithStaticProperty.StaticPropertyIndexed2(1,2) <- 3
```

The only semi-exception to this is that an `Item` property on an instance `x` can be called via `x.[...]` (that is, `Item` is omitted and brackets are used around the arguments).

Comment: So `x.[...]` syntax is only valid on an instance?

Comment: @Stringer - it's even more specific than that - it's only valid for instance properties named "Item".

Comment: @Stringer Actually, it's valid for whatever instance property is named by the type's `System.Reflection.DefaultMemberAttribute`.  If the type is not decorated with that attribute, the default is `Item`.  Example: `[<System.Reflection.DefaultMember("Foo")>] type C() = member x.Foo with get i = i;; let three = C().[3];;`

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to recover the `Type.Prop.[args]` notation, then you can define a simple object to represent an indexable property with the `Item` property:

```
type IndexedProperty<'I, 'T>(getter, setter) =
  member x.Item 
    with get (a:'I) : 'T = getter a
    and set (a:'I) (v:'T) : unit = setter a v

type ObjWithStaticProperty =
    static member StaticPropertyIndexed1 = 
      IndexedProperty((fun x -> 3), (fun x v -> ()))

ObjWithStaticProperty.StaticPropertyIndexed1.[0]
```

This returns a new instance of `IndexedProperty` every time, so it may be better to cache it. Anyway, I think this is quite nice trick and you can encapsulate some additional behavior into the property type.

A digression: I think that an elegant extension to F# would be to have *first-class properties* just like it has *first-class events*. (You could for example create properties that automatically support `INotifyPropertyChange` with just one line of code)